What is the maximum of $ \frac{\sin(n(x+a))}{\sin(x+a)} + \frac{\sin(n(x-a))}{\sin(x-a)}$?
We know the global maxima of the function $\frac{\sin(nx)}{\sin(x)}$
is $n$ (thanks to this question), but

what is the global maxima of
$\frac{\sin(n(x+a))}{\sin(x+a)} + \frac{\sin(n(x-a))}{\sin(x-a)}, \text{ where $a$ is a constant term?}$

Background: It represents the intensity of a narrow-slit diffraction grating but in a more specific application.
Attached is a plot of the maximum absolute value vs $a$ for different $N$. There definitely seems to be an expression which relates the maxima, $a$, and $N$.

and the MATLAB code used to produce the results of above image:
N = 40;
x = -pi/2:0.001:pi/2;
a = -pi/2:0.01:pi/2;

% figure;
for i = 1:length(a)
    y = sin(N*(x + a(i)))./sin(x+a(i)) + sin(N*(x - a(i)))./sin(x-a(i));    
    temp(i) = max(abs(y));
    % hold on;plot(x,y);
end

figure;plot(a,temp)

Edit: Here is a link to the desmos graph

The function can be expressed as $U_{n-1}(\cos(x+a)) + U_{n-1}(\cos(x-a))$ using the Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind, but I don't know if that makes the task simpler.

Why is this question closed? The last line gave the background on why it is relevant to me. I can't get into the specifics without going deep into engineering/physics principles involved

It seems that if the maximum is not at $x=0$, then there are closed forms for $n=1,\dots,7$. Otherwise, high degree polynomials need to be solved like here

Mods, can I post the same question in mathoverflow?

Discussion on the special case in @user64494's answer.
The maximum of
$$f(x) := \frac{\sin 4(x + 1)}{\sin(x + 1)}
+ \frac{\sin 4(x - 1)}{\sin(x - 1)}$$
is given by
$$f_{\max} = \frac{8\sqrt{6}}{9} (2 - 3\cos 2)\cos 1\, \sqrt{\frac{2 - 3\cos 2}{1 - 2\cos 2}}$$
when e.g.
$$x = \arccos \sqrt{- \frac{(2 - 3\cos 2)\cos 1}{6\cos 3}}.$$
Here we just compare my result with @user64494's. The first 500 digits of them are the same (I only input 500).

Based on the plots I have shown in the question, it seems the below equation gives an approximation of the maximum$$N + \frac{sin(2Na)}{sin(2a)}$$ .
The cyan colored plots are plots of the above equation while the red, blue and black plots are obtained by finding the maximum programmatically.
Of course, I still don't know why this is the case. Hopefully this helps us in finding/proving the expression for maximum.


1. Question Restatement to Reference its Equations and Link

We know the global maxima of the function
$$f\left(n,x\right)
=\frac{\sin(nx)}{\sin(x)} \text{ is } n $$ $$\tag{Eq. 1.1}$$
(thanks to this question), but what is the global maxima of
$$g\left(n,a,x\right)
=\frac{\sin(n(x+a))}{\sin(x+a)} + \frac{\sin(n(x-a))}{\sin(x-a)}, \text{ where $a$ is a constant term?}$$ $$\tag{Eq. 1.2}$$

Not stated directly, but instead by the linked reference, of course $n \in 
\{\text{Set of Integers}\}$ and $n>0$.   The $n$ positive integer requirement results in a finite series in the answer.
Notice that $g(n,a,-x)=\frac{\sin(n(-x+a))}{\sin(-x+a)} + \frac{\sin(n(-x-a))}{\sin(-x-a)}=
\frac{\sin(n(-x+a))}{\sin(-x+a)} + \frac{\sin(n(x+a))}{\sin(x+a)}$ $=
\frac{\sin(n(x-a))}{\sin(x-a)} + \frac{\sin(n(x+a))}{\sin(x+a)}$, so that $g(n,a,x)=g(n,a,-x)$ and $g$ is an even function of $x$.  That means that locally $g$ can be expanded as an even Taylor series in $x$, being $g(n,a,x)\approx g_0+g_1\,x+g_2\,x^2+...$.  But since $g$ is even in $x$ then $g_1\to 0$ and only $g(n,a,x)\approx g_0+g_2\,x^2+...$ with a local minimum or maximum at $x=0$.
2. Solution Steps
All of the graphs show that a maximum occurs at $x=0$.  But why?
From the article Prove that $\sin n\theta=n\sin \theta-\frac{n(n^2-1)}{3!}\sin^3\theta+\frac{n(n^2-1)(n^2-3^2)}{5!}\sin^5\theta+\cdots$.  From the answer given by Paramanand Singh is quoted:

$$\sin n\theta = n\sin \theta - \frac{n(n^{2} - 1^{2})}{3!}\sin^{3}\theta + \frac{n(n^{2} - 1^{2})(n^{2} - 3^{2})}{5!}\sin^{5}\theta - \cdots\tag{2}$$

Thus for $\sin n\theta$ all terms are divisible by $\sin \theta$, even in the limit that $\theta \to 0$ but not of course for $\theta=0$.  Now the quantity $\frac{\sin n \theta}{\sin \theta}$ can be calculated:
$$\frac{\sin n \theta}{\sin \theta}
=n - \frac{n(n^{2} - 1^{2})}{3!}\sin^{2}\theta + \frac{n(n^{2} - 1^{2})(n^{2} - 3^{2})}{5!}\sin^{4}\theta - \cdots$$
Similarly,
$$\frac{\sin n \left(x+a\right)}{\sin \left(x+a\right)}
=n - \frac{n(n^{2} - 1^{2})}{3!}\sin^{2}\left(x+a\right) + \frac{n(n^{2} - 1^{2})(n^{2} - 3^{2})}{5!}\sin^{4}\left(x+a\right) - \cdots$$
And,
$$\frac{\sin n \left(x-a\right)}{\sin \left(x-a\right)}
=n - \frac{n(n^{2} - 1^{2})}{3!}\sin^{2}\left(x-a\right) + \frac{n(n^{2} - 1^{2})(n^{2} - 3^{2})}{5!}\sin^{4}\left(x-a\right) - \cdots$$
So,
$$
\frac{\sin n \left(x+a\right)}{\sin \left(x+a\right)}+
\frac{\sin n \left(x-a\right)}{\sin \left(x-a\right)}
=
n - \frac{n(n^{2} - 1^{2})}{3!}\sin^{2}\left(x+a\right) + \frac{n(n^{2} - 1^{2})(n^{2} - 3^{2})}{5!}\sin^{4}\left(x+a\right) - \cdots
\\+
n - \frac{n(n^{2} - 1^{2})}{3!}\sin^{2}\left(x-a\right) + \frac{n(n^{2} - 1^{2})(n^{2} - 3^{2})}{5!}\sin^{4}\left(x-a\right) - \cdots
$$
$$\tag{Eq. 2.2}$$
Now evaluate the derivative of the quantity
$sin^{2\,m}\left(x+a\right)+sin^{2\,m}\left(x-a\right)$ at $x \to 0$ using the Taylor Series Expansion for $\sin\left(y\right) \to y-\frac1{6}y^3+...$ :
$$\left.\frac{d}{d\,x}
\left(
sin^{2\,m}\left(x+a\right)+sin^{2\,m}\left(x-a\right)
\right)\right|_{x\to 0}
=$$
$$\to \left. \left(
n \left(x+a\right)^{2\,m-1}+\left(\text{Higher Order Terms of x}\right)+
n \left(x-a\right)^{2\,m-1}+\left(\text{Higher Order Terms of x}\right)
\right)\right|_{x\to 0}$$
Given that $2m-1$ is always odd then *the terms in $a$ cancel in the limit $x\to 0$, resulting in a maximum there since $n>0$ and it is an integer.  This is the same result as in the graphs which all show the global maximum at $x=0$.  Note that both $\sin\left(n\,x\right)$ and $\sin\left(x\right)$ over a period of $x \to q\,2\pi$, where $q$ is some arbitrary integer.  However, the global maximum value itself does not change.
The maximum is simply $g_{maxiumum}=g |_{x=0}$:
$$g\left(n,a,x\right)_{maximum}
=\left.\left(
\frac{\sin(n(x+a))}{\sin(x+a)} + \frac{\sin(n(x-a))}{\sin(x-a)}
\right)\right|_{maximum\,x\to 0}$$
The maximum is given by:
$$
\boxed{g\left(n,a,x\right)_{maximum}
\to \left.\left(
\frac{\sin(n(a))}{\sin(+a)} + \frac{\sin(n(-a))}{\sin(-a)}
\right)\right|_{maximum\,x\to 0} \to 
\left. \left(2\,\frac{\sin(n(a))}{\sin(a)}\right)\right|_{maximum\,x\to 0}
}
$$
Note:  that this result was referencing the graphs in the question that all had local maxima at $x=0$.  A local minimum is also possible at $x=0$.
3. Example plot of $
y=\frac{\sin\left(4\cdot\left(x+1\right)\right)}{x+1}+\frac{\sin\left(4\cdot\left(x-1\right)\right)}{x-1}
$with $n=4$ and $a=1$
In the comments section, there is a link to the plot of
$$
y=\frac{\sin\left(4\cdot\left(x+1\right)\right)}{x+1}+\frac{\sin\left(4\cdot\left(x-1\right)\right)}{x-1}
$$
The Desmos plots of the same equations show a difference as pictured (and quoted) below:



Looking at the equations within the above plot, it is easy to see what is happening.  The function $g$ is at a minimum at $x=0$.  In this case there are two maxima, one at $g=a$ and the other at $g=-a$.  Plugging either of these and taking the appropriate limit results in the maximum for $g$ just like the equations in the linked plot.  Comparing the result for $g$ between $x=0$ and $x=a$ allows for determining the absolute maximum.
4. Maxima Discussion for $y=g\left(n=6,a=1.5,x\right)_{maximum}
=\left.\left(
\frac{\sin(n(x+a))}{\sin(x+a)} + \frac{\sin(n(x-a))}{\sin(x-a)}
\right)\right|_{n=6,a=1.5}
$
When $n>0$ as in this case, then the maximum or maxima are positive.  Also, since $g(n,a,x)$ is an even function, then for the purposes of calculating the second derivative $g(n,a,x)$ can be approximated as a Taylor series (where $g_1=0$ since g is an even function) for the first powers of $x$ as:
$$g(n,a,x)\approx g_0 + g_2\,x^2+\,\text{Higher order powers of x}$$
$$\tag{Eq. 4.1}$$
which according to Equation 2.2 is:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\sin n \left(x+a\right)}{\sin \left(x+a\right)}+
\frac{\sin n \left(x-a\right)}{\sin \left(x-a\right)}
&=\\
&= n - \frac{n(n^{2} - 1^{2})}{3!}\sin^{2}\left(x+a\right) + \\
&+ \frac{n(n^{2} - 1^{2})(n^{2} - 3^{2})}{5!}\sin^{4}\left(x+a\right) - \cdots +\\&+
n - \frac{n(n^{2} - 1^{2})}{3!}\sin^{2}\left(x-a\right) + \\ &+\frac{n(n^{2} - 1^{2})(n^{2} - 3^{2})}{5!}\sin^{4}\left(x-a\right) - \cdots
\end{align}
$$
$$\tag{Quoted Eq. 2.2}$$
Applying the Taylor expansion for $\sin x \approx x +\, \text{Higher order terms of $x$}\, $ then:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\sin n \left(x+a\right)}{\sin \left(x+a\right)}+
\frac{\sin n \left(x-a\right)}{\sin \left(x-a\right)}
&\approx\\
&\approx  
   n - \frac{n(n^{2} - 1^{2})}{3!}\sin^{2}\left(x+a\right) +\cdots \\
&+ n - \frac{n(n^{2} - 1^{2})}{3!}\sin^{2}\left(x-a\right) +\cdots \\
\end{align}
$$ $$\tag{4.2}$$
$$
\frac{\sin n \left(x+a\right)}{\sin \left(x+a\right)}+
\frac{\sin n \left(x-a\right)}{\sin \left(x-a\right)}
\approx  
   n - \frac{n(n^{2} - 1^{2})}{3!}\left(x+a\right)^2 +\cdots 
 + n - \frac{n(n^{2} - 1^{2})}{3!}\left(x-a\right)^2 +\cdots
\\ \approx 2\,n-2\,\frac{n(n^{2} - 1^{2})}{3!}\left(x^2+a^2\right)+\cdots
$$
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d^2}{d\,x^2}\left.\left(
\frac{\sin n \left(x+a\right)}{\sin \left(x+a\right)}+
\frac{\sin n \left(x-a\right)}{\sin \left(x-a\right)}
\right)\right|_{x \to 0}
&\approx   
\frac{d^2}{d\,x^2}\left.
\left( 
2\,n-2\,\frac{n(n^{2} - 1^{2})}{3!}\left(x^2+a^2\right)+\cdots
\right)\right|_{x\to 0}
\\ &\approx \left.
\left( 
-2\frac{n(n^{2} - 1^{2})}{3!}\left(1\right)+\cdots
\right)\right|_{x\to 0}
\end{align}$$
$$\tag{Eqs. 4.3}$$
When the second derivative in Equation 4.3 is negative, then there is a local maximum at $x=0$ since in this case $g_2$ in Equation 4.1 $g(n,a,x)\approx g_0 + g_2\,x^2+\,\text{Higher order powers of x}$ is negative, indicating locally around $x\to 0$ an upside down parabola.  The other case, occurs when there is a local minimum at $x=0$, in which case there are two maxima for $g(n,a,x)$, each of equal value since $g(n,a,x)$ is an even function of $x$.
Thus the result is to calculate two values, and take the maximum of the two of them to be the global maximum for $n > 0$ of course.  Because all of the minima of $\frac{sin n\,x}{x}$ are less in magnitude than $n$, the maxima (if two) for $g(n,a,x)$ are always positive as for $g(n,a,x=0)$.
5. Maxima Calculation for $y=g\left(n=6,a=1.5,x\right)_{maximum}
=\left.\left(
\frac{\sin(n(x+a))}{\sin(x+a)} + \frac{\sin(n(x-a))}{\sin(x-a)}
\right)\right|_{n=6,a=1.5}
$
Consider now the problem referenced in the comments section:
$$g\left(n=6,a=1.5,x\right)
=\frac{\sin(6\cdot (x+1.5))}{\sin(x+1.5)} + \frac{\sin(6\cdot (x-1.5))}{\sin(x-1.5)}$$ $$\tag{Eq. 5.1}$$
To determine the global maximum, $g(6,1.5,x)$ needs to be evaluated at two limits, $x\to 0$ and $x\to 1.5$ to find for which of these limits $g(6,1.5,x)$ is a global maximum.  Of course, if $g(6,1.5,x)$ turns out to be the maximum between the two, then because $g$ is an even function of $x$, then there are actually two maxima, each of equal value, namely $g_{maximum\,1}=g_{maximum\,2}=g(6,1.5,x)\lim_{x\to 1.5}$.
Hence, Equation 5.1 is first evaluated (using $sin()$ with $()$ being Radians) for the limit $x\to 0$:
$$g_1\left(n=6,a=1.5,x \to 0\right)
=\left.
\frac{\sin(6\cdot (x+1.5))}{\sin(x+1.5)} + \frac{\sin(6\cdot (x-1.5))}{\sin(x-1.5)}\right|_{\lim x \to 0}=$$
$$
=\frac{\sin(6\cdot (1.5))}{\sin(1.5)} + \frac{\sin(6\cdot (-1.5))}{\sin(-1.5)}=0.549 \, \text{from the Desmos online calculator}
$$
$$g_2\left(n=6,a=1.5,x \to 1.5\right)
=\left.
\frac{\sin(6\cdot (x+1.5))}{\sin(x+1.5)} + \frac{\sin(6\cdot (x-1.5))}{\sin(x-1.5)}\right|_{\lim x \to 1.5}=$$
$$
=\frac{\sin(6\cdot (3))}{\sin(3)} + 6=5.749670917743
\,\,\text{And $g_2=5.749670917743$ is the expected }\textbf{maximum}.
$$
$$\tag{Eqs. 5.2}$$
6. Plots for $y=g\left(n=6,a=1.5,x\right)_{maximum}
=\left.\left(
\frac{\sin(n(x+a))}{\sin(x+a)} + \frac{\sin(n(x-a))}{\sin(x-a)}
\right)\right|_{n=6,a=1.5}
$
Consider now the problem referenced in the comments section:
$$g\left(n=6,a=1.5,x\right)
=\frac{\sin(6\cdot (x+1.5))}{\sin(x+1.5)} + \frac{\sin(6\cdot (x-1.5))}{\sin(x-1.5)}$$ $$\tag{Reference to Eq. 5.1}$$
Let $g\to y$ and plot it accordingly in two dimensions using the Desmos plotter resulting in the following quoted plot:



The equations used in the above plot were as follows:
$$
y=\left(\frac{\sin\left(6\cdot\left(x+1.5\right)\right)}{x+1.5}\right)+\left(\frac{\sin\left(6\cdot\left(x-1.5\right)\right)}{x-1.5}\right)\\
y=5.749670917743\,\text{ , }\,
y=0.549\,\text{ , }\,
x=-1.5\,\text{ , and }\,
x=+1.5
$$
$$\tag{Eqs. 5.1}$$
As can be seen, the results are as expected, with $y_{maximum}=5.749670917743$ which occurs at $x=-1.5$ and also the same value at $x=1.5$.  Also, at $x=0$ there is a local maximum of $y_{x=0}=0.549$, but this is not a global maximum.  That is why the two values need to be compared to arrive at the final result.

Not all those functions attain their maximum at $x=0$. Here is a plot of $g(4, 1, x)$: link

It is not clear to me what your statement is. Note that more cases are possible. As an example, $g(6, 1.5, x)$ attains its global maximum at $x \approx 1.2$, with a local maximum at $x=0$ and a local minimum at $x \approx 0.55$.
